# How to integrate logging with winston into logstash-kibana

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, logstash, winston

I am trying to use the newer version of winston.js (3+) together with logstash(kibana).

I got C# projects in which I used log4Net and in the log4Net.config file I added the address + port to the logstash server (Kibana) and I managed to integrate the log files into it.

But now in my Node.js project nothing I tried works

I got a separate js file for logging and it looks as follow :

```
const config = require('config');
const winston = require('winston');
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');

const elasticsearch = require('winston-elasticsearch');

const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
const client = new Client({ node: my_logstash_ip_address })

const esTransportOpts = {
    client: client
  };

const transport = new(winston.transports.DailyRotateFile)({
    filename: config.log.absPath,
    datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    prepend: true,
    level: config.log.logLevel
});

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        transport,
        new elasticsearch(esTransportOpts)
    ]
});

module.exports = {
    writeToLog(level, message) {
        if (message) {
            const date = new Date();
            if (level === 'debug')
                logger.debug(`${date.toJSON()} ${message}`);
            else if (level === 'info')
                logger.info(`${date.toJSON()} ${message}`);
            else if (level === 'error')
                logger.error(`${date.toJSON()} ${message}`);
            else
                logger.error(`${date.toJSON()} not a valid log level for: ${message}`);
        } else {
            logger.error(`${new Date()} log message cannot be empty!`);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
null: ResponseError: Response Error
body: Object
headers: Object
message: "Response Error"
meta: Object {body: Object, statusCode: 404, headers: Object, …}
name: "ResponseError"
stack: "ResponseError: Response Error
    at IncomingMessage.response.on (p:\...\node_modules\@elastic\elasticsearch\lib\Transport.js:302:25)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1103:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)"
statusCode: 404
__proto__: ElasticsearchClientError {constructor: , body: <accessor>, statusCode: <accessor>, …}
```

I read on the winston.js github page they made changes with the transports logic and that now I might be needing to use a "format" feature?

But then I also saw something like the code I added above which aint working for me either.

My goal is to manage to connect my winston logger to my logstash server (Kibana) so I will see my logs on the logstash/kibana server

Answer (score 3):

```
> npm install winston@2.4.1
> npm install winston-logstash@0.4.0
```

then

```
const winston = require('winston');
require('winston-logstash');

winston.add(winston.transports.Logstash,
{
    port: your-port,
    host: 'your-logstash-host',
    ssl_enable: true,
    max_connect_retries: -1,
});

...

winston.error('This is a test error log message', { custom: 'my custom field', Environment: 'local' });
```